# Is there a canonical place to store arbitrary key/value pairs in Active Directory

Tags: active-directory

This question is about how/where to store arbitrary key-value pairs in Active Directory.  Can it be used, in a pinch, as a data-store like that, assuming the number of such items would be in the dozens not in the thousands?

Is there a canonical place in the hierarchy to store them?

Is there any restriction on the character encoding or any restrictions on which characters can be used?  Could **value** be a `json` string?

Answer (score 1):

There is no attribute created for that purpose, but there are plain-text attributes that are often unused that you can use for whatever you want.

For example, there is a [`comment`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/adschema/a-info) attribute that I have never seen used.

The only issue would be the character limit. Most of the plain-text attributes have a limit of 1024 characters.